# Fragment inside Viewpager not show when revisited

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragment, fragmentpageradapter

I have two fragments in my Activity. One contains a viewpager which also has two fragments in it. Everything works fine but the problem is when i re-visit the fragment containing the viewpager from the other fragment, the child fragments in the viewpager are never shown.

This is the fragment containing the viewpager, **MainHistoryFragment.java**

```
public class MainHistoryFragment extends Fragment {


View view;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_hist, container, false);


    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    SectionsPagerAdapter sectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getActivity(), getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
    ViewPager viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(sectionsPagerAdapter);
    TabLayout tabs = view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    tabs.getTabAt(0).setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_email);
    tabs.getTabAt(1).setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_compass);
}
```

}

and this is the class subclassing the FragmentPagerAdapter, **SectionsPagerAdapter**

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

@StringRes
private static final int[] TAB_TITLES = new int[]{R.string.tab_text_1, R.string.tab_text_2};
private static final int totalTabs = 2;
private final Context mContext;

public SectionsPagerAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
    switch (++position){
        case 1:
            return new HistoryFragment();
        case 2:
            return new BookmarkFragment();
            default:
                return null;
    }
}

@Nullable
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return mContext.getResources().getString(TAB_TITLES[position]);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return totalTabs;
}
```

}

I noticed that the getItem() method of the SectionsPagerAdapter never gets called after a revisit.
Please how do i get my fragments in the viewpager to show after a revisit?

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
SectionsPagerAdapter sectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getActivity(), getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
```

to:

```
SectionsPagerAdapter sectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getActivity(), getActivity().getChildFragmentManager());
```

You need to use getChildFragmentManager() when u are adding another fragment inside a fragment.

Hope this helps! Happy Coding!